# insert file in folder google drive

Tags: vb.net, file, google-drive-api, directory

I want to insert file in folder,  after searching in this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert) , i try to do it

there is my code :

```
'folder creation
Dim dossier = New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
dossier.Title = dat_sauv.SelectedItem
dossier.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
Dim rep = Service.Files.Insert(dossier)
rep.Fields = "id"

Dim ref As New ParentReference()
ref.Id = dossier.Id
MessageBox.Show(dossier.Id)
Dim file = rep.Execute()
' file creation
Dim f As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
f.Title = fichier_txt.Text
f.Description = " fichier drive"
f.MimeType = "text/plain , image/jpeg"
Dim s As Integer
s = f.Id

Try
    Dim r = Service.Parents.Insert(ref, s).Execute()

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

but the error is :

[image]

and i can't resolve this error.
and when i change the type of s to string , the error message is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, import operations will return a 400 error if the file format is not supported. With this, you may want to try [specifying file names and extensions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/file).

> Apps should specify a file extension in the title property when inserting files with the API. For example, an operation to insert a JPEG file should specify something like `"name": "cat.jpg"` in the metadata.

Also, noted in [`Files: insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert),

> Apps creating shortcuts with `files.insert` must specify the MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk`.

Lastly, see also [Migrating from Google Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#v2) for more information.

Comment: thank you for your help , the folder in google drive don't have extension 


but , i found the solution and it work , i didn't make ParentReference() correct , i make it in the wrong place